# How to pass testCase value to next one with Pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, parameterized-unit-test

```
import pytest


def add(x):
    return x + 1

def sub(x):
    return x - 1


testData1 = [1, 2]
testData2 = [3]


class Test_math(object):
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('n', testData1)
    def test_add(self, n):
        result = add(n)
        testData2.append(result) <-------- Modify testData here
        assert result == 5

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('n', testData2)
    def test_sub(self, n):
        result = sub(n)
        assert result == 3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main()
```

there are only 3 tests :`Test_math.test_add[1]`,`Test_math.test_add[2]`,`Test_math.test_sub[3]` executed in this scenario.

`Test_math.test_sub` only executes with predefined data `[3]` which is not my expectation `[2,3,3]`. How to fix it?

> update [1,2,3]-> [2,3,3]

Comment: Why is `[1,2,3]` your expectation? You're giving to `test_sub` the list `testData2` which is only one element long. Ok, I see why you could have expected somethign different.

Comment: I think `testData2.append(result)` will modify the testData2, and new testData2 will pass to next execution, but it doesn't

Comment: That's a bad design in my opinion (more details in answer), it might be possible to achieve that by placing `testData1` and `testData2` as class attributes instead (haven't tested that).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure why it didn't work, but doing it like that it's a bad idea since the order of tests is not guaranteed (unless you implement ad-hoc code to order the execution of tests).

Besides this and other issues of test design, the way you can somewhat achieve what you want would be by joining `testData1` and `testData2` in the `pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('n', testData1 + testData2)
def test_sub(self, n):
    result = sub(n)
    assert result == 3
```

Now, keep in mind that with your test definition, this will always fail because the result of `sub(n)` with `testData1 + testData2` will never be `3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytest

def add(x):
    return x + 1

def sub(x):
    return x - 1


testData1 = [1, 2]
testData2 = [3]


class Test_math(object):
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('n', testData1)
    def test_add(self, n):
        result = add(n)
        testData2.append(result) 
        assert result == 5, "FAILED"
        return testData2

    def add():
        for i in testData1:
            res = add(i)
            testData2.append(res)  
            print(testData2)         
        return testData2

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('n', add())
    def test_sub(self, n):
        result = sub(n)
        assert result == 3, "FAILED"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main()
```