# How can I pass the result of one pytest to another pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am new to pytest and currently testing out different functionality. 
I currently have a testcase where I test out an endpoint, get a response, and this response has to be used in another test case to another endpoint, of which the result will be sued in a third testcase.

In a regular python script, this would be very simple (easy error handling as well).

Is it possible to daisy chain test cases using pytest AND pass results (possibly as variables) from one test to the other?

Comment: That's not how automated test should be done. Every single test should be self-contained and do these steps: 1. Create the test's pre-conditions, 2. Run the code, 3. Assert the results, 4. Clean up. If 1. Is similar for multiple test, use a fixture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass testCase value to next one with Pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375060/how-to-pass-testcase-value-to-next-one-with-pytest)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining tests and passing an object from one test to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238725/chaining-tests-and-passing-an-object-from-one-test-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

That's bad practice. You do not want tests to be dependent.